# How do we add a cursor on an animated plot with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mouse-cursor, matplotlib-animation, matplotlib-widget

I am trying to build some kind of a game where you have to keep the cursor as close as possible to a line. For this I animated a piecewise function with animation.FuncAnimation and added a crosshair cursor.

The problem is that the cursor disappears when it's not moving and each movement triggers some "blinking". How can I make it smooth ?

By the way, I am planning afterwards to define some scoring system by measuring the distance between the cursor and the line at each frame.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = range(120)
Y = [4, -1, 0, -2, -3, -5, 0, 2, 1, 3]
y = []
for i in range(14 * 60):
    if i <= 180:
        y.append(0)
    elif 180 < i <= 240:
        y.append((i - 180) * Y[0] / 60)
    elif 240 < i <= 300:
        y.append((i - 240) * (Y[1] - Y[0]) / 60 + Y[0])
    elif 300 < i <= 360:
        y.append((i - 300) * (Y[2] - Y[1]) / 60 + Y[1])
    elif 360 < i <= 420:
        y.append((i - 360) * (Y[3] - Y[2]) / 60 + Y[2])
    elif 420 < i <= 480:
        y.append((i - 420) * (Y[4] - Y[3]) / 60 + Y[3])
    elif 480 < i <= 540:
        y.append((i - 480) * (Y[5] - Y[4]) / 60 + Y[4])
    elif 540 < i <= 600:
        y.append((i - 540) * (Y[6] - Y[5]) / 60 + Y[5])
    elif 600 < i <= 660:
        y.append((i - 600) * (Y[7] - Y[6]) / 60 + Y[6])
    elif 660 < i <= 720:
        y.append((i - 660) * (Y[8] - Y[7]) / 60 + Y[7])
    elif 720 < i <= 780:
        y.append((i - 720) * (Y[9] - Y[8]) / 60 + Y[8])
    elif 780 < i <= 840:
        y.append(Y[9])

line, = ax.plot(x, y[0:120])


def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(y[0 + i:120 + i])  # update the data.
    return line,


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=20, blit=True, save_count=50)

plt.xlim([0, 120])
plt.ylim([-6, 6])

v1 = ax.axvline(55, color='pink', lw=2, alpha=0.7)
v2 = ax.axvline(65, color='pink', lw=2, alpha=0.7)
ax.fill_betweenx([-6, 6], 55, 65, color='pink', alpha=0.5, transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform())

cursor = Cursor(ax, useblit=True, color='red', linewidth=1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: If you're making a game, why are you using `matplotlib` instead of, saying, `pygame`?

Comment: I did not know about pygame. Thanks it actually looks way more adapted yes!